# How do I ensure that a variable updates only on the last entry in the form field?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a feature that shows based on the person's desired height input how much is left. I have a variable called heightRemaining that let's say has a value of 100. When a person tries to add a new image and enters a height for it heightRemaining will -= with that number to show how much height they'd have left if they chose that number. If they decide to change their input from 40 to 50 I want the height remaining to just show the latest calculation (if you enter 40 it'll show 60, if you enter 50 it'll show 50 remaining). It keeps adding however numbers and inputed and resetting the height remaining each time there is a change in input.

Right now I am using:

this.data.remainingHeight -= defaultHeight

to calculate and display that. But it keeps adding each change and showing the wrong height remaining (So if you select 40 and then 50, height remaining will show 10 instead of 50).

Comment: Yep that will do that.  Try something like `this.data.remainingHeight = totalHeight - defaultHeight;` Where totalHeight is your 100 value.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small program to easily simulate what you may want to achieve. Feel free to correct me again

```js
class Foo{
     constructor(height){
         this.remaingingHeight = height;
    }

    addImage(height){
        this.remaingingHeight -= height;
        if(this.remaingingHeight <= 0){
            //code if it hits 0
        }
    }

    getRemainingHeight(){
        return this.remaingingHeight;
    }
}

const foo = new Foo(100);
console.log("Initial Height "+foo.getRemainingHeight());

foo.addImage(20);
console.log("First Addition "+foo.getRemainingHeight());

foo.addImage(30);
console.log("Second Addition "+foo.getRemainingHeight());
```

Output (Node v18.16)

[image]

**The answer below does not meet the criteria**
I hope this helps you

```js
let desiredHeight = 100; //the height desired by person

this.data.remainingHeight = desiredHeight - defaultHeight;

// Ex: desiredHeight = 100, defaultHeight = 40
// this.data.remainingHeight = 60
```

From your example of changing value from 40 to 50, this will modify value of `this.data.remaingingHeight` to 50 as, 100 - 50 = 50

Comment: Sorry my explanation was a bit unclear. So this data.remainingHeight starts off at 100, but then if you add one image it'll get down to let's say 80. Then if the next one is 30 I'd need it to get down to 50 not 70. So even though it starts at 100 it changes with each item that's added until it hits 0.

Comment: I updated my answer and hope it is correct now